# Passing a collection of a subclass as collection of superclass

Tags: java

I have a POJO that looks more or less like this:

```
public class Action {
    private String eventId;
    private List<ActionArgument> arguments;
    //action to perform when this action is done
    private List<Action> onCompleteActions;

    public Action() {
    }

    public Action(String eventId, List<ActionArgument> arguments, List<Action> onCompleteActions) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.arguments = arguments;
        this.onCompleteActions = onCompleteActions;
    }

    public String getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }
    public void setEventId(String eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }
    public List<ActionArgument> getArguments() {
        return arguments;
    }
    public void setArguments(List<ActionArgument> arguments) {
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }
    public List<Action> getOnCompleteActions() {
        return onCompleteActions;
    }
    public void setOnCompleteAction(List<Action> onCompleteActions) {
        this.onCompleteActions = onCompleteActions;
    }
}
```

and I have an extending class that looks like this:

```
public class UserDefinedAction extends Action {
    //for reordering actions with the default actions
    private String doBefore;
    private String doAfter;
    private String doAfterComplete;

    public String getDoBefore() {
        return doBefore;
    }

    public void setDoBefore(String doBefore) {
        this.doBefore = doBefore;
    }

    public String getDoAfter() {
        return doAfter;
    }

    public void setDoAfter(String doAfter) {
        this.doAfter = doAfter;
    }

    public String getDoAfterComplete() {
        return doAfterComplete;
    }

    public void setDoAfterComplete(String doAfterComplete) {
        this.doAfterComplete = doAfterComplete;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere I have a service I would like to do this:

```
...
UserDefinedAction udAction = new UserDefinedAction();
udAction.setOnCompleteAction(new ArrayList<UserDefinedAction>());
```

I thought this should work because a `UserDefinedAction` IS an `Action` because its extending it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UserDefinedAction` may be an `Action`, but a `List<Subclass>` is *not* a `List<Superclass>`.  As you have defined it, your `setOnCompleteAction` method must take a `List<Action>`, so it cannot accept a `List<UserDefinedAction>`.

Comment: So I need to override that method in order to get around it?

Comment: I think you can declare a `List<? extends Action>` instead... ie, `private List<? extends Action> onCompleteActions;`

Comment: Overriding won't help, because that would change the type of the parameter.  Any workaround here would need to involve generics to define a bounded generic type parameter to replace `Action` in `List<Action>`.

Comment: Hey guys, i really appreciate the help. That gives me a lot to go on. +1's all around.

Comment: Alternately, you could simply declare your other `ArrayList<UserDefinedAction>` as `ArrayList<Action>` and simply add your `UserDefinedAction`s to that list

Comment: FYI, +1s are nice, but if an answer solves your problem, marking as answer is nicer

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I explained why the code as provided doesn't work, despite `UserDefinedAction` being an `Action`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Hmm. Then what would have been the answer?

Answer (score 5):

`List<UserDefinedAction>` **is not** a subclass of `List<Action>` even if `UserDefinedAction` extends `Action`. In order you can pass a `List<UserDefinedAction>` to your service, change the `UserDefinedAction#setOnCompleteAction` method to receive a `List<? extends Action>`, now you can pass a `new ArrayList<UserDefinedAction>()`.

More info:

- [Generics: Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)